# Having issues using AOS animation with svelte kit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, aos.js

I'm using for the first time svelte for a portfolio and coming from React I must say it's really fun and easy to use !

But recently i had issues using AOS with svelte kit. Mostly when I'm going from a page to another using href the animations won't load. But when i'm refreshing the page (with cmd+R) it works again.

[The link to the repo](https://github.com/AlexandreHoumeau/portfolio-clara-marchand)

I'm using this method in my __layout.svelte. Putting it in onMount or not doesn't change anything.

```html
    onMount(() => {
        AOS.init();
    });
```

Then in another page i'm using AOS like below

```html
        <h1
            data-aos="slide-right"
            data-aos-duration="1000"
        >
            Allianz France
        </h1>
```

And to go from page to page i'm using

```html
            <a
                href="allianz"
                sveltekit:reload
                out:fly|local={{ x: -200, duration: 1000, delay: 300 }}
                in:fly={{ x: 200, duration: 1000, delay: 1300 }}
                id="allianz"
            >
```

Using sveltekit:reload does not change anything.

package.json

```
"aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6"
```

Comment: please post the relevant code in the question instead of an offsite link

Answer (score 0):

The AOS (**A**nimate **o**n **S**croll) library will look inside the DOM for elements with the data-aos attributes, it even watches for DOM changes.

That feature has limitations. When Svelte manages the DOM or the layout changes based on other factors the AOS library needs a little help.

```js
AOS.refresh();
```

When you should call that method depends on your app.

**Tip**: For debugging add `window.AOS = AOS;` inside an `onMount`, that allows calling the `OAS.refresh()` from the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, I'm going to try this right away !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing to import the `aos.css` file?

Your `+layout.svelte` file should look like this kind of:

```
<script lang="ts">
   import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
   // @ts-ignore
   import AOS from "aos";

   import { onMount } from 'svelte';

   onMount(() => {
      AOS.init();
   });
</script>

<slot/>
```